# INserting value in mysql DB using python

Tags: python, sql, string-formatting

Here is my Mysql table schema

Table: booking
Columns:

```
id  int(11) PK AI
apt_id  varchar(200) 
checkin_date    date 
checkout_date   date 
price   decimal(10,0) 
deposit decimal(10,0) 
adults  int(11) 
source_id   int(11) 
confirmationCode    varchar(100) 
client_id   int(11) 
booking_date    datetime 
note    mediumtext 
Related Tables:property (apt_id → apt_id)
booking_source (source_id → id)
```

I am trying to insert the value using python .so Here what I have done

```
sql = "INSERT INTO `nycaptBS`.`booking` (`apt_id`, `checkin_date`, `checkout_date`, `price`,`deposite` `adults`, `source_id`, `confirmationCode`, `client_id`, `booking_date`) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%d','%d','%s','%d','%s' )"   %  (self.apt_id,self.start_at,self.end_at,self.final_price,self.deposit,self.adults,self.source_id,self.notes,self.client_id,self.booking_date,self.notes)  
x.execute(sql)
```

But while executing the above script I am getting the error .

```
    sql = "INSERT INTO `nycaptBS`.`booking` (`apt_id`, `checkin_date`, `checkout_date`, `price`,`deposite` `adults`, `source_id`, `confirmationCode`, `client_id`, `booking_date`) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%d','%d','%s','%d','%s' )"   %  (self.apt_id,self.start_at,self.end_at,self.final_price,self.deposit,self.adults,self.source_id,self.notes,self.client_id,self.booking_date,self.notes)  
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not NoneType
```

I think my strings formatter are not correct Please help me out .

Answer (score 0):

it looks like either booking_date, notes, source_id, (also you are inserting notes value 2x?)
is `None`.  You could check/validate each value before inserting.

Also please use parameterized queries, NOT string formatting

> Usually your SQL operations will need to use values from Python
>   variables. You shouldn’t assemble your query using Python’s string
>   operations because doing so is insecure; it makes your program
>   vulnerable to an SQL injection attack (see http://xkcd.com/327/ for
>   humorous example of what can go wrong).
>
> Instead, use the DB-API’s parameter substitution. Put ? as a
>   placeholder wherever you want to use a value, and then provide a tuple
>   of values as the second argument to the cursor’s execute() method.

something like:

`x.execute("INSERT INTO thing (test_one, test_two) VALUES (?, ?)", (python_var_one, python_var_two,))`

Comment: actually it should be VALUES(%s, %s) instead of VALUES(?, ?)